# JQuery Datatable with parent child relationship in same dataset. How to display it as parent child rows in the table?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, parent

I have a nested dataset. Few records in the dataset are child to other records in the same dataset. The records that have parent as null do not have any child elements, but ones that has value associated with is will indicate its parent in same dataset. How do I represent this in jQuery Datatable with Parent Child relationship.

I have just manipulated the common dataset to explain my requirements. As in the dataset example below, Record with Name - **Tiger Nixon** have two child records, which are as seperate records in the same dataset.

An example of how to achieve would be of great help.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "parent": "null",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "parent": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "parent": "null",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "parent": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) to store original data in `g_dataFull` and filter and return data containing parents only to be displayed in the main table.

When child row is being in `format()` function you need to iterate full dataset `g_dataFull` and find and display rows containing children (`this.parent === d.name`).

> **DEMO**

```js
var g_dataFull = [];

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" width="100%">';
      
    var dataChild = [];
    var hasChildren = false;
    $.each(g_dataFull, function(){
       if(this.parent === d.name){
          html += 
            '<tr><td>' + $('<div>').text(this.name).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.position).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.office).html() +'</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.salary).html() + '</td></tr>';
         
          hasChildren = true;
       }
    });
  
    if(!hasChildren){
        html += '<tr><td>There are no items in this view.</td></tr>';
     
    }
  
 
    html += '</table>';
    return html;
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
          "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/3mbye",
          "dataSrc": function(d){
            
             g_dataFull = d.data;
             var dataParent = []
             $.each(d.data, function(){
                if(this.parent === "null"){
                   dataParent.push(this);  
                }
             });
            
             return dataParent;
          }
        },
         
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can I know how can I add Search for parent as well as child rows together.

Comment: Outstanding.  This really helped a lot.  Does anyone know how to get the child columns to line up with the parent columns?

Comment: It looks like the child row displays a <table> inside of a <td>.  I just want to display that child row in one of the rows of the parent table so everything will line up properly.

Comment: How to expand all rows by default on page load, I tried this but no luck `$("#example").DataTable().rows().every(function () {
            var tr = $(this.node());
            this.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        });`

Comment: @Dotnet, please see [jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/)

Comment: From there only I copied that code but on load it is not expanding, where as on button click it is

Comment: Also for my child I may have some child's in that case how can we load the table

Comment: Child rows are not lining up properly can you help me