# JQuery DataTables - Style Child Rows

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

So I'm recreating the solution from this post.

[JQuery Datatable with parent child relationship in same dataset. How to display it as parent child rows in the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025134/jquery-datatable-with-parent-child-relationship-in-same-dataset-how-to-display)

Take a look at the accepted answer and run the code.

You have a table like this, with child rows.

[image: Table image]

Those child `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are created inside of another `<table>` which is embedded inside of **another** `<tr>` and `<td>` tag.  If you have FireBug installed, click on Inspect Element to see this.

[image: Inspect]

Take a look at the `<tr>` line in dark blue and the `<td>` below it.  It looks like those are automatically created by something.  I can't see where those are coming from.  I want to have my child `<tr>` and `<td>` elements (currently inside the table in the light blue line) in the same order as the parent columns.  I can strip out the `<table>` element, but I don't see why this is all embedded in a `<td>`.  Can anyone see a way to have my child elements appear in a row just like any other?

One final thought.  Is there any chance these rows would show up on an export?
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: "Why this is all embedded in a `<td>`?" This is the way Datatables [child rows work](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). If you want your child elements to appear "in a row just like any other" maybe you don't want child rows at all... Do you want child rows to show/hide when you click a button on the parent? What is your source data like?

Comment: Yeah I want it to behave the same way.  I'm using an ajax source.  I have a SQL query that pulls the totals row (the parent) unioned to the details rows (children).  It all comes back together.  This is the only example I've found out there how to split up data from the same source.  By returning the child row in that td, it falls out of line with the parent row width, but I may be stuck with that.