# JQuery Datatable child row alignment not matching with parent column

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, datatables

I really need your help in aligning the child row columns along with parent row columns. I found an example exactly matches what I did, So I am not putting the entire code here as there is a restriction in my company. So I am giving the reference here where the code/example is available. 
Example: [JQuery Datatable with parent child relationship in same dataset. How to display it as parent child rows in the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025134/jquery-datatable-with-parent-child-relationship-in-same-dataset-how-to-display)

I have attached the screenshot of the alignment. Can anyone please help. 
Note: I tried putting some CSS html table cellspacing/cellpadding, but it didn't workout.[image]

```js
var g_dataFull = [];

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" width="100%">';
      
    var dataChild = [];
    var hasChildren = false;
    $.each(g_dataFull, function(){
       if(this.parent === d.name){
          html += 
            '<tr><td>' + $('<div>').text(this.name).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.position).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.office).html() +'</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.salary).html() + '</td></tr>';
         
          hasChildren = true;
       }
    });
  
    if(!hasChildren){
        html += '<tr><td>There are no items in this view.</td></tr>';
     
    }
  
 
    html += '</table>';
    return html;
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
          "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/3mbye",
          "dataSrc": function(d){
            
             g_dataFull = d.data;
             var dataParent = []
             $.each(d.data, function(){
                if(this.parent === "null"){
                   dataParent.push(this);  
                }
             });
            
             return dataParent;
          }
        },
         
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't be lazy, instead post example code yourself in here.

Comment: Sorry can you explain the problem a bit more clearly?  My understanding is you are asking how to make the children line up directly with the parents when you click on the green plus button?

Comment: @jack: added code, actually copied the code from another post.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt: The problem is as shown in the image, the columns in the child row is not aligned correctly to the parent columns. the child columns are aligned towards right.

Comment: @SK, you found a solution, but didn't post the answer?

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still looking for answer then you need to add the `$` to the child element HTML. Below is the example showing the same.

```
function format ( d ) {
  return $('<tr>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.position+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.office+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.start_date+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.salary+'</td>'+
    '</tr>');
}
```

The `$` after the return statement does the trick. For more reading you can visit the [this thread from datatable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61725/child-row-with-parent-row-with-matching-columns).

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
table#example table {
    padding-left: 25px!important; /* maybe you put another value instead of 25 */
}
```

Try without using important first.

```js
var g_dataFull = [];

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" width="100%">';
      
    var dataChild = [];
    var hasChildren = false;
    $.each(g_dataFull, function(){
       if(this.parent === d.name){
          html += 
            '<tr><td>' + $('<div>').text(this.name).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.position).html() + '</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.office).html() +'</td>' + 
            '<td>' +  $('<div>').text(this.salary).html() + '</td></tr>';
         
          hasChildren = true;
       }
    });
  
    if(!hasChildren){
        html += '<tr><td>There are no items in this view.</td></tr>';
     
    }
  
 
    html += '</table>';
    return html;
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
          "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/3mbye",
          "dataSrc": function(d){
            
             g_dataFull = d.data;
             var dataParent = []
             $.each(d.data, function(){
                if(this.parent === "null"){
                   dataParent.push(this);  
                }
             });
            
             return dataParent;
          }
        },
         
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
table#example table {
    padding-left: 25px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks jack for your time and help. I tried that, it is only pushing the first column towards right. Not other columns.

Comment: Now you need to show your code. Give link to jsfiddle or something

Comment: Probably you are not selecting the css properly.

Comment: I verified my code, also I have taken all your code and tried. but the same result.

Comment: Maybe your html is different than your posted code in here. That's why I need to see the code. You can create a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks Jack. As you said I did put the entire code.

Comment: For now I got a solution. I put fixed column for all columns except the last column. and then in the format() function put css width for all columns except the last columns. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your time to help me. But I have a request. I can't ask questions as I have few -ve voted questions. could you please up vote my question, so I can ask questions in stackoverflow?